# How to declare type in NGRX Effect V10? Classes no longer used so Type not inferred

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

So since the V10 upgrade to NGRX you can no longer pass in a type of Action to the effect, as Actions are now declared as functions isntead of classes. Is there still a way to handle this in V10?

```
export const myAction = createAction(
    '[myAction]',
    props<{person: User}> ()
);

@Effect({ dispatch: false })
    x = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType**<myAction>**('[myAction]'),
```

I don't have access to person prop. Where in before version 10 you did because it was a class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#incorporating-state

1. Pass `myAction` directly to `ofType`
2. The action is typed according to its props, so you can just use `action.person`

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
  x = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(myAction),
    map(action => of(action.person))
  );
```

Also it would be preferable to use the new `createEffect` syntax.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-ngrx-oftype?file=index.ts

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this @wlf. The problem seems to still present though saying that "Property 'person' does not exist on type 'never'. Any thoughts towards this?

Thanks for showing the new syntax, I wasn't aware this had changed :).

Comment: In my stackblitz the types are correct. You can check by hovering `action` inside the map or using intellisense to see the members. It's probably down to how you are using the preceding operators - check against my example and if you can't get it working create a stackblitz (or fork from mine) and I'll have a look.

Comment: I've seen my mistake, I was still passing in the string like the old way, opposed to passing in the action creator. I didn't realise that they had changed this. Thanks for your support!

**if anyone else is experiencing this problem, pass in the actionCreator not the string and you're good to go. Curtousey of @wlf".